# Matplotlib set_y/xlabel doen'nt work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to simply set my x and y label of my subplot, I don't understand what I do wrong? the code doesn't give me an error, it just doenst show the labels.
The code that calls the update_figure function isn't shown below. Update_figure is called every second. but I expect the set_xlabel function in the init function.

can someone help me to fix this problem?

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
"""Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
    self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.axes.autoscale(False)
    #We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
    self.axes.hold(False)

    self.axes.set_title('Sharing x per column, y per row')
    self.axes.set_ylabel('time(s)')
    self.axes.set_ylim(0, 100)

    self.compute_initial_figure()

    FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
    self.setParent(parent)

    FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

def compute_initial_figure(self):
    self.axes.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], scaley=False)

class MyDynamicMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
"""A canvas that updates itself every second with a new plot."""
yAxe = [0]
xAxe = [0]
i = 0
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    MyMplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # self.a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    # timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    # timer.timeout.connect(self.update_figure)
    # timer.start(1000)

def update_figure(self):
    # Build a list of 4 random integers between 0 and 10 (both inclusive)
    self.yAxe = np.append(self.yAxe, (getCO22()))
    self.xAxe = np.append(self.xAxe, self.i)
    # print(self.xAxe)
    if len(self.yAxe) > 10:
        self.yAxe = np.delete(self.yAxe, 0)

    if len(self.xAxe) > 10:
        self.xAxe = np.delete(self.xAxe, 0)
    self.axes.set_ylabel('time(s)')
    self.axes.plot(self.xAxe, self.yAxe, scaley=False)
    self.axes.grid(True)
    self.i = self.i + 1

    self.draw()
```

thx in advance!

Comment: You never call the function `update_figure` in which you `set_ylabel`.

Comment: I do call that function, but didn't show that code, thx for noticing though

Comment: it is to much code to post till u can execute. as you see in the init function in call self.axes.set_ylabel("string") and so in the update method. But It still doenst show anything.

Comment: Produce a minimal complete valid example -- take out all the stuff that *isn't* causing problems so you can post a runnable example that shows exactly the problem. That's both the job of the asker and vital practice at debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have

```
self.axes.hold(False)
```

the plot and figure (including labels, title and axes limits) are cleared every time you call plot.

You need to retain the `hold(False)` for the type of plot you are doing.

Therefore, you need to move the `self.axes.set_title('...')` and `self.axes.set_ylabel(...)` and any other such commands underneath the `self.axes.plot(..)` in the `update_figure()` function.